# Problema con rutas proyecto laravel en local host -> htdocs

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

Tengo mi proyecto de laravel en el escritorio, cuando corro el comando `php artisan serve`, el proyecto funciona perfectamente.

Ahora lo puse en htdocs para correr mi proyecto sin el comando y funciona también me sale el login y todo, el problema es que yo manejo ajax y al cargar el dashboard del proyecto voy a una ruta y traigo información, ahí es donde ocurre el problema, me dice que no encuentra la ruta.

Por lo que he estado viendo es que la ruta la consulta directamente por ejemplo `/usuarios` y no detecta, sale error 404 como puedo solucionar eso? para que funcionen mis rutas con  normalidad sin necesidad del `php artisan serve`?

[image: Esto me sale en el div que tendria que regresar con ajax]

Comment: Podrías [editar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/270112/edit) la pregunta y subir el código del `AJAX`. Revisa [mcve]

Answer (score 1):

Modifica o crea el archivo .htaccess en la raíz del proyecto para que apunte a la carpeta public. El siguiente ejemplo es para hosting compartido pero creo que te serviria si dejas el dominio como localhost.

```
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^nombreDominiso.co$ [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.nombreDominio.co$
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !public/
    RewriteRule (.*) /public/$1 [L]
```